# Is there a single adjective to describe an attachment target?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can attach a picture file to an email.

The picture file is `"attachable"`, is there a single word adjective that describes quality of the email that it can be attached to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the picture can be attached to the email, the picture is *attachable* and the email is *attachment-capable*.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***attachment-bearing***?

It doesn't necessarily roll off the tongue, but that's what I'd probably use.

EDIT: Even before @TrevorD pointed it out, I realized my response wrongly addresses an email that ***has*** an attachment rather than one ***capable of*** having one. *Mea culpa*.

Comment: That's useful, do you know of another common suffix synonymous with bearer that I could use to make a single compound word?

Comment: How about **upload-bearer**?

Comment: What is the context, @StuperUser?

Comment: -1 Surely the e-mail is not actually attachment-bearing *until the attachment has been attached*? The question asked about an e-mail that *can have an attachment* - not one that *already* has an attachment.

Comment: True, @TrevorD. My answer wasn't responsive. I was actually going to point that out myself.

Answer (score -1):

Could you say - this software is **upload-friendly**, ***attachment-friendly*** or ***attachment-enabled***?

Comment: Read the question. 1. OP is asking about an **e-mail** - not software in general. 2. Q. is about **attachments** not uploads. 3. OP wants a term relating to an e-mail **with** an attachment. "friendly" has no meaning of "attached".

Comment: O well, attachment-friendly or attachment-enabled then?

Comment: Actually, @TrevorD, might you be changing your mind here with your point #3? Earlier you pointed out (rightly, I thought) that the OP was asking about an email that *can have an attachment*. Thus, *attachment-friendly* or *attachment-enabled*, as per user49727, would work.

Comment: @JeffCohan & user49727. *Mea culpa*! Sorry, my comments above were incorrect & Jeff is correct: OP was asking about an email *that can have an attachment*. I've deleted my second comment above. In my first comment "with" is wrong. Thanks Jeff for pointing out my error.

Comment: LOL! What are we who comment in online English Language and Usage forums good at if *not* pointing out others' errors? :-)